# CSS Animation Switch between two images

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a lower third. I got the images ready but I'm not sure how I can switch between two images using CSS Animation.
The animation is going to be infinite looped and I'm going to change the opacity of image01 to 100% at X percent in to the animation and image02 to 100% at Y percent in to the animation. I'm going to animate it so it comes from the left side of the screen and in later that's why I have '*left: -1229px;*' below in the css code.

Div setup:

```
<body>
    <div id="cf">
        <div class="l_com"></div>
        <div class="l_cha"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm using this css code to set the images: (I'm going to animate 'left' later)

```
.l_com{
    background-image: url(/img/image01.png);
    width: 1229px;
    height: 108px;
    position: absolute;
    /*left: -1229px;*/
    opacity: 100;

}
.l_cha{
    background-image: url(/img/image02.png);
    width: 1229px;
    height: 108px;
    position: absolute;
    /*left: -1229px;*/
    opacity: 100;

}
```

Now, for testing I'm using this CSS code for the animation to be able to see it quickly and make changes if something is wrong:

```
#cf{
    -webkit-transition: all 60s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: animation;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;    
}
```

so the name of the animation is 'animation'.
Is there a way I can animate a specific div inside the main div with the id 'cf'
the code I tested is this (and no I don't think it's correct at all but I'll just put it here so you might get a better idea of what I'm trying to do)

```
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
   .l_com.opacity: 0; 
  }
  20% {
    .l_com.opacity: 0; 
  }
  21% {
    .l_com.opacity: 100;
  }
  25% {
    .l_com.opacity: 100;
  }
  26% {
    .l_com.opacity: 0;
  }  

  40% {
    .l_cha.opacity: 0; 
  }
  41% {
    .l_cha.opacity: 100;
  }
  45% {
    .l_cha.opacity: 100;
  }
  46% {
    .l_cha.opacity: 0;
  }     
  100% {    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example with `animation-duration: 3s` and `animation-delay: 8s`.

If you see the `@keyframes` rules, you'll notice that opacity remains same from `0%` to `36.36%` and from `63.63%` to `100%`. That is the delay(`4s` each). The rest is when the animation happens.

```
   0%   9.09%  18.18% 27.27% 36.36% 45.45% 54.54% 63.63% 72.72% 81.81%  100%

   1s     2s     3s     4s     5s     6s     7s     8s     9s    10s    11s
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+  
|      |      |      |      ||||||||||||||||||||||      |      |      |      |  
|      |      |      |      ||||||||||||||||||||||      |      |      |      |  
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+  
 9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09%  9.09% <------------+
^                           ^                    ^                           ^            |
|                           |                    |                           |            |
+-----------36.36%----------+-------27.27%-------+----------36.36%-----------+ <------+   |
|                           |                    |                           |        |   |
0%                        36.36%               63.63%                      100% <-+   |   |
^                           ^                    ^                           ^    |   |   |
|                           |                    |                           |    |   |   |
+-----------delay-----------+-----animation------+-----------delay-----------+    |   |   |
^                           ^      duration      ^                           ^    |   |   |
|                           |                    |                           |    |   |   |
|                           |                    |                           |    |   |   |
+-----show first image------+-------change-------+-----show second image-----+    |   |   |
                                    image                                         |   |   |
                                                                                  |   |   |
                                                                                  |   |   |
                           +-----------------------------+                        |   |   |
                           |  - 0% + 36.36% = 36.36%     |                        |   |   |
                           |  - 36.36% + 27.27% = 63.63% | <----------------------+   |   |
                           |  - 54.54% + 36.36% = 100%   |                            |   |
                           +-----------------------------+                            |   |
                           |  - 9.09% x 4 = 36.36%       |                            |   |
                           |  - 9.09% x 3 = 27.27%       | <--------------------------+   |
                           +-----------------------------+                                |
                           |  - 100% / 11s = 9.09%       | <------------------------------+
                           +-----------------------------+
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
#container div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url(http://s25.postimg.org/6gpp81xn3/fff.png);
}
#container div.bottom {
  opacity: 1;
  background-image: url(http://s25.postimg.org/jwcpxi64v/fff.png);
}
#container div.top {
  -webkit-animation: anim 11s infinite alternate;
  animation: anim 11s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36.36% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  63.63% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  36.36% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  63.63% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I can work with that @chipChocolate.py thanks

Comment: [You can safely ditch and not use all the prefixes apart from `-webkit-`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for the animation propertes.